# how to select closest class and its id with closest method

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="demo">
    <div class="moduletable">
        <div class="demo">
            <div class="demo-wrap">
                <div class="container" id="button-1">Button-1 contents</div>
                <div class="ctrl">
                    <div><a href="#buttton-1">Button-1</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('ctrl').click(function(){
```

> $(this).closest('.container #button-1').width();
>
>      // how to select the class **container** first and then  its id that is **button-1**
>
> }

**Edit**

```
<div class="container" id="button-1">Button-1 contents</div>
<div class="container" id="button-2">Button-2 contents</div>
<div class="ctrl">
<div><a href="#buttton-1">Button-1</a>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I get container width as its id if one button is pressed it should alert button-1 width and if another it should alert button-2.

Comment: in my try var mywidth=$(this).closest('.container #button-1').width => then alert(mywidth) not showing the width. it's showing null.

Comment: var btn_width = $($(this).find('a[href]').attr('href')).width()

Comment: If you want to select the button you don't need the class as the id has to be unique on your page. So simply do `$('#button-1').width();`

Comment: I was supposing to do with closest so, I was doing it for #button-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it as the [previous sibling](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
$(this).prev(".container")
```

Then grab it's id:

```
$(this).prev(".container").prop("id");
```

**edit:** To get it's width:

```
$(this).prev(".container").width();
```

Comment: what are the differences between prev() and closest() function

Comment: `prev` selects the previous *sibling*. `closest` searches for *parents*. In your case, `container` is a sibling of `ctrl`, not a parent

Comment: and what if $(this).closest('.demo').sibling('.container') is this right?

Comment: No, because `container` must be *beside* the element in the tree, i.e. In your example, `ctrl` is a sibling (beside) `container`. The following classes can be found instead using `closest`: demo-wrap, demo and moduletable

Comment: actually I've two div with class container and want to get the width from its id that are different button-1 and button-2. how can I get that width.

Comment: Updated answer accordingly

Comment: @NavinRauniyar This should be a new question. This page is littered with answers to your previous requirement

Comment: No, actually I wanted to ask that but couldn't make understand. So, Sorry for that. anyway I'll accept your answer if what I'm searching for answer could not get.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
$('.ctrl').click(function(){
    alert($(this).prev(".container").attr('id'));
});
```

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/e6VXD/)

To find the width:

```
$('.ctrl').click(function(){
    alert($(this).prev(".container").width());
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I want to get its width I tried $(this).prev(".container").attr('id').width(); but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".ctrl").on("click",function(){
       alert($(this).parent().parent().find('.container').attr("id"));
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/QTzrB/6/)

Hope it helps you